# Deny access to anonymous users not working on Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to do simple protection of a folder inside my web application. From the documentation seems very straight forward. Yet, it does not work for me.

I have a razor page with a folder called keys, with some text files there. From the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I have tried:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages(options => {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/keys");
        });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        ....
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

Yet, once I start the application and I type on the browser:

https://localhost:44312/keys/clear.txt

The server is definitely sending back the page. Any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments under Cameron's answer have confused me a bit, so my answer may not be what you want to do.

Anyway, you can use `app.UseStaticFiles()` to add middleware to protect that folder. As it's middleware, you need to insert it into the correct place in your pipeline for it to work. Here is the complete `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // Notice that this is the second time we're calling UseStaticFiles().
    // The first call is to configure CSS and things to be served.
    // This is deliberately called after UseAuthentication().
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/keys"))
            {
                // As the files are sensitive, don't cache a response.
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store");

                if (!ctx.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    ctx.Context.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                    ctx.Context.Response.Body = Stream.Null;
                }
            }
        },
        // It's the combination of the `FileProvider` and `RequestPath` that 
        // maps the `MyKeys` physical folder to the `/keys` path.
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "MyKeys")),
        RequestPath = "/keys"
    });

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

In the example above, `MyKeys` is a folder at the root of your project, and `/keys` is the path used to request a file:

```
ProjectName
| wwwroot
  | css
  | etc
| Pages
  | your razor pages
| MyKeys
  | clear.txt
```

If the user is not authenticated, they will receive a 401 response. We deliberately do not cache the results, as the files are sensitive. You could, of course, do something more here, such as requiring a user to have a particular role, or redirecting them if they're not signed in. It's up to you.

Comment: thank you! I was wondering if I can have these files inside the server and NOT under the wwwroot.

Comment: @gmmo No problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions protecting routes in a folder handled by ASP.NET Core and not files on the filesystem. If you need to protect a resource, then you should write a resource handler to serve the file and protect the route and/or controller.

It should be something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ResourceController : ControllerBase {
  // Other Protected Resources
  
  [HttpGet("keys/clear")]
  public IActionResult Clear() {
    var file = Path.Combine("secure/path", "clear.txt");
    return PhysicalFile(file, "text/plain");
  }
}
```

Note, since you are using a resource handler, you can move the clear.txt file to another directory that is not publicly accessible. It will need to be readable by your application user.

If the application is running in IIS, then the folder will need to have read permissions for the IIS Application Pool Identity. If it is running on Linux, then you'll need to grant read permissions to the user that is running the server.

Comment: How do I do this? I don't really want these files on the public directory, but I don't want them part of the compilation as well. The problem the only API I found to read files from the server was by using something like: keysRootFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "keys"); This only works for files inside the wwwroot. I was wondering how I can read files that are NOT inside the wwwroot. Thx!

Comment: I've updated my answer to change to an arbitrary "secure" path. You will need to grant the IIS Application Pool or the user running ASP.NET Core read permission to this directory.

Comment: How can I write the custom handler? I see your answer, but I don't understand. I see no links to the doc to do that. Where do I put that piece of code you just pasted?